# ICS file generated by MS Booking via MS Graph API Create Appointment contains unexpected contents

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, microsoft-graph-booking

We have been using MS Bookings and MS Graph API (v1.0) for a while now via SDK (v4.52.0) - recently (as of a couple of weeks ago) one of our customers has raised that the ICS file generated when an appointment is created has started to contain more information than expected.

Before this was reported by the customer, the ICS file would contain the "sevice notes" only, however now it is containing the following information, which is confusing end users:

> ### Customer Info
>
> Name: John Doe
> Email: john.doe@email.com
> Phone Number: 000000000000
>
> ### Booking Info
>
> Service name: IT Support
> Location: { }
> Price: Free
>
> ### Custom Fields
>
> ### Buffer time:
>
> Before: 0min(01:30 PM Tue, 18 Jul 2023).
> Time with customer: 01:30 PM Tue, 18 Jul 2023–02:00 PM Tue, 18 Jul 2023
> After: 0min(02:00 PM Tue, 18 Jul 2023)
> Time zone:W. Europe Standard Time
>
> ### Internal Notes
>
> Original service note on create

Kindly find below the request body for create appointment:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/appointments`

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "customerTimeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "smsNotificationsEnabled": false,
    "priceType": "free",
    "startDateTime": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2023-07-18T13:30:00.0000000+00:00",
        "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "endDateTime": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2023-07-18T14:00:00.0000000+00:00",
        "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "isLocationOnline": false,
    "optOutOfCustomerEmail": true,
    "anonymousJoinWebUrl": null,
    "serviceId": "redacted",
    "staffMemberIds": [
        "redacted"
    ],
    "maximumAttendeesCount": 1,
    "filledAttendeesCount": 1,
    "reminders@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingReminder)",
    "reminders": [
        {
            "offset": "P1D",
            "recipients": "allAttendees",
            "message": "This is a reminder for both customer and attendees"
        },
        {
            "offset": "PT1H",
            "recipients": "customer",
            "message": "Please be available to enjoy your lunch service."
        },
        {
            "offset": "PT2H",
            "recipients": "staff",
            "message": "Please check traffic for next cater."
        }
    ],
    "customers@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingCustomerInformation)",
    "customers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingCustomerInformation",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "emailAddress": "john.doe@email.com",
            "phone": "000000000000"            
        }
    ],
    "serviceName": "IT Support",
    "serviceNotes": "Original service note on create"
}
```

We have attempted to investigate possible settings both from within the SDK and on MS Bookings, but can't spot anything that might be related to this. We have also tested to create bookings via postman directly, and it results in the same behaviour. Only when the appointment is created through the calendar in MS Booking this information is not sent in the ICS.

Is there any configuration setting which we can use to remove this information? When creating the booking manually through MS Bookings, this extra information is not in the ICS file - but only when it is created via the SDK or API only.

Thank you !